# Breeze Js loading of very big Int64 values

Tags: javascript, serialization, numbers, breeze, int64

We have problem with loading all very big Int64 values from server to client. I think problem is for all numbers larger then 25776087313154050. 
We using No DB approach of Breeze and makes all metadata manually. Here is metadata:

```
store.addEntityType({
    shortName: "AdditionalInfoType",
    namespace: "Services",
    autoGeneratedKeyType: breeze.AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity,
    dataProperties: {
        id: {dataType: breeze.DataType.Int64, isNullable: false, isPartOfKey: true },
        name: { dataType: breeze.DataType.String, isNullable: true },
        dataType: { dataType: breeze.DataType.String, isNullable: false, defaultValue: 'Unknown' }
    },
    navigationProperties: {
        enumItems: {
            entityTypeName: "AdditionalInfoEnumValue", isScalar: false, associationName: "AdditionalInfoEnumValue_AdditionalInfoType"
        }
    }
});
```

Here is what Fiddler showing from server (data is correct here):

```
[{"$id":"1","$type":"Services.AdditionalInfoType, Services",
"Name":"Shoe Size","DataType":"Numeric","EnumItems":null,"Id":25776087313154051},
{"$id":"2","$type":"Services.AdditionalInfoType, Services",
"Name":"Floating Holiday","DataType":"Date","EnumItems":null,"Id":25776087313154050}]
```

Breeze query is pretty simple:

```
entityQuery.from('AdditionalInfoTypes')
            .toType(entityNames.additionalInfoType)
            .using(employeeManager)
```

And here what we have in client (unfortunately I can not post images here):

```
entity[0].id == 25776087313154052
entity[1].id == 25776087313154050
```

So, Id for second entity correctly loads and have value: `25776087313154050` for both client and server. But for `25776087313154051` server value on client its `25776087313154052`.
I did some experiments and found that problem reproducable for all numbers > 25776087313154050 (for both Key part and not). Every time breeze loader increase number by 1.

Any ideas where me wrong or how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a problem related to breeze. The library will simple try to assign the primitive types directly to the properties of the entity. It's  apparently an issue with the JavaScript. I think you're reaching the maximum value of the Number type.

Simple try to assign the 25776087313154051 to a property and you will get the value 25776087313154052.

I'm not sure but it seems to be a strange issue with how JavaScript deals with large numbers. May be you can get more info in reading the spec. http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5.

What you might try to do to avoid the problem is to change the type of the id property to string.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I also found that JavaScript does not support 64 bit integers. But its very strange that Breeze have not workaround inside to support such datatype, it allow to set data type in metadata but not support serialization. Your workaroud with Int64 -> String convertion working fine and looks like we should never use Int64 breeze datatype.

Comment: I'm glad it's working for you. Could you mark the question as answered?

Comment: Yep, I will, just waiting other ideas, may be somebody know more efficient solution related to Breeze.